# Remove repetition in php

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I want to create a search bar

I give order to the visitor the chose category and city
for the first I select ALL from category table in database, but about city I have a problem, I Select City from projects, but I have the same city in many projects.

I want to remove the repetition if the city it's in many projects

this's the php code

```
$sql_city = "SELECT city FROM project";
$run_city = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_city);
while($rows_city = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_city)){

    echo '<option value="">'.$rows_city['city'].'</option>';

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [DISTINCT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html) keyword in query

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM project
```